# On a linux system what is the purpose of the .profile file

Tags: playonlinux

On a linux system what is the purpose of the .profile file
I know a small amount on this topic but I need an explanation of the purpose of the .profile file and a explanation of the contents.

Answer (score 0):

The profile file is dotfile (filename starts with a period, so the command ls will not show it by default) that the shell being used looks for and executes when the user logs in and starts the shell session. The file will contain the users customisations for the shell, such as their shell prompt and any aliases they have made. It is usally located at ~/.profile (specifically ~/.bash_profile for bash) however modern shells usually have more advanced configuration options and often have plugin managers (fsh and zsh are notable examples)
Thats all I know about it hope it helps